# Laravel 4 - Access to Table through Relational Models

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

Edit: typo

I have two Models: Project and Task. Both are relational to each other:

Project.php

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    public function tasks() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }
```

Task.php

```
class Task extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
```

Through my ProjectsController I pass the necessary Variables to my Projects View, like this:

ProjectsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::with('tasks')->get();

    return View::make('projects.index')
        ->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

And in my View I loop through every Project to show everything on a table:

#### Projects List

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Titel</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Tasks</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach($projects as $project)

    <tr>
        <td>{{$project->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->title}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->description}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->task}}</td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
</table>
```

As you can see, the last td-Tag, should access data from the tasks table.
I know that the above View does not work. But I want to know in general, how I would go about it, if I want to output the **number of tasks, each project has**.

Or anything else, that explains, how I can access different tables, through relational Models, in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you defined the project model with `$this->hasMany('Task');` and fetched models **with** their tasks, you can simply do

```
{{ $project->task()->count() }}
```

be sure to call the tasks as if it were a function, instead of a property.

Comment: Thank you, I just came back to this thread to post the same answer.